# CanOnMenuItemClick not binded corretly in generic eventhandler

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

To make an abstraction for the topmenuitems implementations i've made a generic method to handle the action through IoC.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Open" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action OnMenuItemClick('OpenFileCommand')]" />
```

This works fine for the OnMenuItemClick event and the initial call CanOnMenuItemClick works.
Thereafter CanOnMenuItemClick is not updated when CanOnMenuItemClick is called. It seems like the UIElement is not binded to the CanOnMenuItemClick method.

```
public void OnMenuItemClick(string cmd)
{            
}

public bool CanOnMenuItemClick(string cmd)    
{            
    ICommand command = _commands.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetType().Name == cmd);
    return command != null && command.CanExecute(null);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I might have got the wrong end of the stick (I'm not near my machine), but usually the convention in `Caliburn.Micro` is to specify guard properties of the form `Can<MethodName>`, rather than methods.

So you'd probably want to add a property.

```
public bool CanOnMenuItemClick
{
    // Your code to determine if `OnMenuItemClick` can be executed.
}
```

I'm not entirely sure from the example what you're doing with your commands, so this likely won't be the entire solution to your problem.

You may need to also need to add calls to `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanOnMenuItemClick);` in methods to alert the UI when you're expecting the execution status of this method to have changed.